# Get list items using REST - Only the first folder is returned

Tags: rest

I am using following to display all the items in content query webpart but only the folder is displayed. What am I missing?
Sharepoint 2013

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.1.0.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
.knockOutTable td {
    background:#f7f7f7;
    padding:10px;
    vertical-align:top;  
    border:1px #fff solid;
}
.knockOutTable #td-alfa{
    font-weight:bold;
    width:20%;
}
.knockOutTable #td-beta, .knockOutTable #td-gamma{
    width:40%;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
var rootSite = "https://swe.sharepoint.com/";
var subSite = "knockout";
var results = [];

function LoadStuff(index) {

    $.ajax({
        url: rootSite + subSite + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('KnockoutList')/items",
        method: "GET",
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"},

        success: function(data){
            results.push.apply(results, data.d.results);
            ko.applyBindings(results);
            },

        error: function (fn, status, error) {
            alert('Error:' + error);
            }

    });
}

$(function(){LoadStuff(0)})
</script>

<div>
    <div data-bind="template:{name:'KoList', foreach:results, as:'rows'}"></div>
    <script type="text/html" id="KoList">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="knockOutTable">
            <tr>
                <td id="td-alfa" data-bind="text:Title"></td>
                <td id="td-beta" data-bind="text:Introduction"></td>
                <td id="td-gamma" data-bind="text:Content"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Content query webpart or content editor webpart?

Comment: Are you trying to get details from SharePoint List or SharePoint Library?

Comment: I tried the above code with Library and list and none seems to be working. but I can see data set in the developer tool console of chrome. ff and ie don't even show the results.

Comment: Melinda, Try this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/184254/display-rest-data hth.

Comment: Try this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/184254/display-rest-data. It worked for another user.

Comment: Try this link http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/184254/display-rest-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Liz,

Here is the post [Display REST Data](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/184254/display-rest-data) that will solve your issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use multiple REST API's calls to expand each of the folder's. Something like

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('KnockoutList')/Items(1)?$expand=folder
```

Where 1 is the ID of the folder

Another approach is to use `SP.CamlQuery` and use `<View scope='RecursiveAll'>`