# Display REST Data

Tags: javascript, rest, content-query-web-part, ajax

I am running into few issues.

**Issue # 1:**

When I use the following REST endpoint uri in chrome I get XML back. However, IE throws an error (IE cannot display this feed). I downloaded REST API Browser and it gives me `401 UNAUTHORIZED Error`.

`url: http://off.mci.il/sites/sales/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Sales By Region')`

**Issue # 2**

I am trying to display a list on a sharepoint page using Content query web part. But following code does not display anything. I can see there are 120 records by going to developer tool > console. Also added alerts so i can see code are being rendered. what is happening ? I would really appreciated if i can get some help on these 2 issues.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//var results = [];
alert('line 6');


$.ajax({
        url: "http://off.mci.il/sites/sales/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Sales By Region')/items",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"},
        cache:false,                
        success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        var items = [];
        $(data.d.results).each(function(){
        items.push('<ul id="' + 'ListUL' + '">' + 
        '<li id="' + 'ListLI' + '">' + 
        this.Title +
        '</li>' + 
        '</ul>');
        });
        items.push("</div>");
        $("#listResult").html(items.join(''))


        $('#JSONData').empty();
        $.each(data.d.results, function( index, value )
        {
        $('#JSONData').append("<h1>" + value.Title + value.ActiveText + value.SoldTo +"</h1>" + "<h2>" + value.Author + "</h2>");
        });


        }
}); 

alert('line 28');


</script>
```

Comment: I can see the data thru developer tool of IE and chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liz,

I was having similar issue but I followed this link http://summit7systems.com/who-needs-a-data-view-web-part-sharepoint-rest-and-datatables-net and it worked perfectly. Following is my code (see if it's helpful)

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
    <thead><th>City</th><th>State(Y/N)</th><th>Last Modified</th></thead>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function LoadCities()
    {
    var call = $.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Lookup Cities')/items",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {
    Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
    }
    });
    call.done(function (data,textStatus, jqXHR){
    $('#example').dataTable({
    "bDestroy": true,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "aaData": data.d.results,
    "aoColumns": [
    { "mData": "City" },
    { "mData": "State" },
    { "mData": "Modified" }
    ]
    });
    });
    call.fail(function (jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
    alert("Error retrieving Tasks: " + jqXHR.responseText);
    });
    }
    window.onload = function(){ LoadCities();};
    </script>
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. No errors at all and I am able to display data.

Answer (score 0):

- You have to explicitly request for a JSON response (if the default response is XML)
- You need to give the server the RequestDigest (unique token) to prove you are who you are

  ```
  headers: {
    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
  }
  ```

Comment: still getting access denied.

Comment: You must be within the same domain. If not it is like trying to get access to your neighbors house

Comment: we only have 1 domain at my company.